# Loop trying to access php pages

Tags: loops, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm experimenting an unknown issue for me. In www.graficaslapaz.com when I pick on any link to other pages, explorer throws an error.

Viewing my log file appears that:

```
[Thu Feb 25 08:58:42.601721 2016] [core:error] [pid 163316:tid 140473331054336] [client 178.7.107.86:57067]
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
referer: http://www.graficaslapaz.com/instalaciones.php
[Thu Feb 25 08:58:42.601758 2016] [core:error] [pid 163316:tid 140473331054336] [client 178.7.107.86:57067]
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
referer: http://www.graficaslapaz.com/instalaciones.php
```

This is the content of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^home home.php
RewriteRule ^empresa empresa.php
RewriteRule ^instalaciones instalaciones.php
RewriteRule ^acceso_clientes acceso_clientes.php

RewriteRule ^nuevo_cliente nuevo_cliente.php
RewriteRule ^enviar_cliente enviar_cliente.php

RewriteRule ^presupuestos presupuestos.php
RewriteRule ^enviar_presupuesto enviar_presupuesto.php

RewriteRule ^subir_archivo subir_archivo.php
RewriteRule ^enviar_archivo enviar_archivo.php

RewriteRule ^suscribete suscribete.php
RewriteRule ^enviar_suscripcion enviar_suscripcion.php

RewriteRule ^trabajos/([0-9]+) trabajos.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^trabajos trabajos.php

RewriteRule ^hp-indigo-digital hp-indigo-digital.php
RewriteRule ^packaging_plus packaging_plus.php

RewriteRule ^equipo_humano equipo_humano.php
RewriteRule ^seccion_empresa/(.*) seccion_empresa.php?seccion=$1

RewriteRule ^oferta oferta.php
RewriteRule ^enviar_oferta enviar_oferta.php

RewriteRule ^contacto contacto.php
RewriteRule ^privacidad privacidad.php
RewriteEngine on
```

I have no idea where is the origin that cause this loop and how to solve it.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have the pattern `^home`. Now, this pattern will match all the following  (and their derivatives):

```
home
home1
homexzs
home.php
```

As you can see, the pattern will match `home.php` and rewrite the URL to `home.php` which matches the pattern yet again, causing infinite rewrites (or internal redirects).

Use the `$` anchor to have an exact match:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(home|empresa|instalaciones|acceso_clientes|nuevo_cliente|enviar_cliente|presupuestos|enviar_presupuesto|subir_archivo|enviar_archivo|suscribete|enviar_suscripcion|trabajos|hp-indigo-digital|packaging_plus|equipo_humano|oferta|enviar_oferta|contacto|privacidad)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^trabajos/([0-9]+) trabajos.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^seccion_empresa/(.*) seccion_empresa.php?seccion=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @DavidSusí Mark the reply as answer.